# Networking the EXT.HDD that is connected to my WDTV device

Tags: external-hard-drive, home-networking, wdtv

I have the WDTV device that really works great. What I am trying to do is to rip my DVD's though my network right to the EXT.HDD that is connected to the WDTV. The problem is that that the WDTV got its own interface and will not work though a computer, it needs its own dedicated HDD. I want to get the EXT.HDD that is hooked into the WDTV and rip my DVD’s to it though the network. The WDTV is not able to be put into the network. I tried a few different NAS devices but it did not work, the WDTV can't see the EXT.HDD in the NAS. The WDTV is connected to the EXT.HDD though a USB port, 
Thanks
Pulling, my hair out.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your only choice is the [Buffalo DriveStation FlexNet](http://www.buffalotech.com/products/external-storage/drivestation/drivestation-flexnet/). It has USB and Ethernet ports along with a front-panel switch to change modes. Unfortunately, reviews indicate that it is on the slow side, so hopefully it is fast enough to stream video.

There are a few other external hard drives that have both USB and Ethernet ports, but will not work for your application.

- The LaCie Ethernet Big Disk and Big Disk Mini both use network-over-USB, which your WDTV will not support.
- The Coolmax CN-570 requires a restart when changing modes. It is also no longer available.

Comment: Review here: http://www.buffalotech.com/products/external-storage/drivestation/drivestation-flexnet/

Comment: Sorry, I meant here: http://www.smallnetbuilder.com/content/view/30654/75/

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are trying to access the USB HDD through two different interfaces at once. Most (if not all) dual interface drives will not allow you to do this.

What you need to be able to do this is a Network Media Tank. These are devices that perform the same as the WDTV but have a network (wired or wireless) connection and can act as network drives (through SMB).

Google 'Popcorn Hour' or 'Egreat' for a couple of the more popular versions.